# Why does a composable recompose while seemingly being stateless (the only passed parameter is a function, not a state)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow, compose-recomposition

I'm updating the uiState by calling a corresponding function via clicking the first composable.
The second composable recomposes because of it, although it doesn't take any state parameters, only another function.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyScetchApplicationTheme {
                Screen(MyViewModel())
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen(myViewModel: MyViewModel) {
    val myUiState by myViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    Column {
        MyBox(myViewModel::changeParameter)       // when clicking this
        MyBox(myViewModel::changeOtherParameter)  // that recomposes
        MyBox{ }                                  // but that one doesn't
        Text("${myUiState.otherParameter}")  // and neither does that one
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MyBox(function: () -> Unit) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .size(80.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .clickable { function() }
    )
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var _uiState = MutableStateFlow(MyUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<MyUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun changeParameter() {
        _uiState.update { it.copy(parameter = !uiState.value.parameter) }
    }

    fun changeOtherParameter() {
        _uiState.update { it.copy(otherParameter = !uiState.value.otherParameter) }
    }
}

data class MyUiState (
    val parameter: Boolean = false,
    val otherParameter: Boolean = false,
)
```

The same composable without a function as an argument doesn't recompose, so it's the function that somehow triggers a recomposition.
_
Why does it happen, and how to avoid this recomposition without ditching the function?
My project becomes laggy due to abundance of unnecessary recompositions.

Comment: `val onClick = remember {myViewModel.someFunction()}`should fix it. You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700668/5457853) out. After Stability Edit section i mention about ViewModel lambdas and other ways to prevent unnecessary recompositions.

Comment: @Thracian thank you for the answer and for the link and the knowledge i get from it, much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome. Did it fix the issue you have?

Comment: @Thracian, is [this article](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2022/08/05/jetpack-compose-recomposition/) wrong in the section labeled **Option 1 - Method References**, that function references such as `myViewModel::someFunction` are stable if the receiver is stable? I don't see why the compiler would treat `myViewModel::someFunction` differently than `{ myViewModel.someFunction() }`.

Comment: @Thracian I'm yet to complete fixing this issue in all places, but your solution indeed works!

Comment: @Tenfour04 Your link is also helpful, thank you! But as you can see, I was using function references, and the reciever seems to also be stable (please correct me if I'm wrong), but there were still recompositions occuring.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i read the article now, i actually thought as the author and i recall function references making lambda stable but testing out further i see that without remember some ViewModel, which is unstable itself, are unstable. Because of that the solution works 100% is capturing lambdas inside remember. I will investigate this further

Comment: Compiler treats myViewModel::someFunction VS { myViewModel.someFunction() } because lambdas are, hunder the hood, anonymous functions, that take the receiver as params (in the case here myViewModel) and myViewModel is considered unstable. By using method reference you avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting function parameter into `remember` prevents recomposing:

```
    val onClick = remember {myViewModel.someFunction()}
```

Credits to @Thracian for the answer in the comments (some useful links are also there)