# Debugging re-compositions from happening

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The lambda I am passing here is to help prevent recompostion `titleTextLayoutResult: (hasVisualOverflow: Boolean, lineCount: Int) -> Boolean`

As this is a LazyColumn every time the user scrolls up and down it creates a lot of recompositions.

I think it is because of this

```
onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
    shouldShowMoreTitle =  titleTextLayoutResult(textLayoutResult.hasVisualOverflow, textLayoutResult.lineCount) 
})
```

I have extracted it into a lambda function thinking this might help but it is still the same. Just wondering is there any solution to this?

I have added the snippets below. But this is the repository in case there is something missing in the snippets.

https://github.com/steve1rm/BusbyNews

```
var shouldShowMoreTitle by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}


@Composable
fun NewsItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    articleModel: ArticleModel,
    onNewsLinkClicked: (newsLink: String) -> Unit,
    newsItemEvent: (NewsItemEvent) -> Unit,
    newsItemState: NewsItemState,
    titleTextLayoutResult: (hasVisualOverflow: Boolean, lineCount: Int) -> Boolean
) {

Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .animateContentSize(),
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
    text = articleModel.title,
    maxLines =  if (showMoreTitleClicked) Int.MAX_VALUE else 1,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
        shouldShowMoreTitle =  titleTextLayoutResult(textLayoutResult.hasVisualOverflow, textLayoutResult.lineCount) 
    })
}

NewsItem(
    articleModel = articleModel,
    onNewsLinkClicked = onNewsLinkedClicked,
    newsItemEvent = newsItemEvent,
    newsItemState = newsItemState,
    titleTextLayoutResult = ::getTextLayoutResult)

private fun getTextLayoutResult(hasVisualOverflow: Boolean, lineCount: Int): Boolean {
    return hasVisualOverflow || lineCount > 1
}
```

I have already using a key for the lazy column as below:

```
LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(6.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                items(
                    key = { articleModel ->
                        articleModel.id
                    },
                    items = newsPagingData.itemSnapshotList.items
                ) { articleModel ->
                    NewsItem(
                        articleModel = articleModel,
                        onNewsLinkClicked = onNewsLinkedClicked,
                        newsItemEvent = newsItemEvent,
                        newsItemState = newsItemState,
                        titleTextLayoutResult = ::getTextLayoutResult
                    )
                }
}
```

This is the recompositions
[image]

Comment: Your snippet doesn't compile. Where are you defining and using `shouldShowMoreTitle`?

Comment: @Jorn I have updated my question with that snippet.

Comment: What recomposition exactly do you have in mind? Also, you should not have mutable variables in your state - that's a first thing to check `ShowMoreOrLessTitleText`

Comment: Please attach debugger and state which arguments are changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is with `NewsState` and there is also issue with newsItemEvent in MainActivity.

First remove NewState from `NewsItem` and `shouldShowProgress` as boolean

```
@Composable
fun NewsItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    articleModel: ArticleModel,
    onNewsLinkClicked: (newsLink: String) -> Unit,
    newsItemEvent: (NewsItemEvent) -> Unit,
    shouldShowProgress:Boolean = false,
//    newsItemState: NewsItemState,
    titleTextLayoutResult: (hasVisualOverflow: Boolean, lineCount: Int) -> Boolean
)
```

Then inside setContent change unstable lambdas by setting

```
        val lambda = remember {
            { newsItemEvent: NewsItemEvent ->
                newsViewModel.onNewsItemEvent(newsItemEvent)

            }
        }

        val themeLambda = remember {
            { appTheme:AppTheme->
                newsApplication.toggleDarkThemeOff(appTheme)

            }
        }
```

And call NewsScreen

```
NewsScreen(
    newsPagingData = newsHeadLines,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .nestedScroll(connection = scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
    topAppBarScrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
    onNewsLinkedClicked = { newsLink ->
        newsLinkState = newsLink
    },
    newsItemState = newsItemState,
    newsItemEvent = { newsItemEvent ->
//                                newsViewModel.onNewsItemEvent(newsItemEvent)
        lambda.invoke(newsItemEvent)

    },
    selectedTheme = useDarkColors,
    onSelectedTheme = { appTheme ->
//                                newsApplication.toggleDarkThemeOff(appTheme)
        themeLambda(appTheme)
    }
)
```

These will eleminate NewsItem recompositions but LazyColumn will be recomposed since `NewsItemItems` read NewsState. I also created a lambda in NewsItemsItems but this optional, i don't think it effects in every situation.

```
val textLayoutResultLambda = remember {
    { hasVisualOverflow: Boolean, lineCount: Int ->
        getTextLayoutResult(hasVisualOverflow, lineCount)
    }
}
```

[image]

I also updated NewState as to remove mutable params but it still triggers recomposition no matter what. You should focus on why NewsState is triggering needless recompositions.

```
@Immutable
data class NewsItemState(
    val shouldShowProgress: Boolean = false,
    val showMoreOrLessTitleText: ShowMoreOrLessTitleText = ShowMoreOrLessTitleText(),
//    val showMoreTitleClicked: Boolean = false,
    val shouldShowMoreTitle: Boolean = true,
    val shouldMoreDescriptionClicked: Boolean = false,
    val shouldShowMoreDescription: Boolean = false,
    val isDarkThemeSelected: Boolean = false
)


/** Work in-progress*/
data class ShowMoreOrLessTitleText(
    val text: String = "Show more",
    val shouldShowMoreTitle: Boolean = false,
    val hasTextOverflow: Boolean = false,
    val lineCount: Int = -1
)

fun ShowMoreOrLessTitleText.textUpdate(): String {
    return if(this.shouldShowMoreTitle)
        "Show more"
    else
        "Show less"
}

fun ShowMoreOrLessTitleText.shouldMoreText(): Boolean {
    return this.hasTextOverflow || lineCount > 1
}
```

And in ViewModel you can update it as

```
is NewsItemEvent.OnShowMoreTitleTextClicked -> {
    _newsItemState.update { newsItemState ->

        val showMoreOrLessTitleText = newsItemState.showMoreOrLessTitleText.copy(
            lineCount = newsItemEvent.showMoreOrLessTitleText.lineCount,
            hasTextOverflow = newsItemEvent.showMoreOrLessTitleText.hasTextOverflow,
            shouldShowMoreTitle =  newsItemState.showMoreOrLessTitleText.shouldMoreText(),
            text =   newsItemState.showMoreOrLessTitleText.textUpdate(),
            )

        newsItemState.copy(
            showMoreOrLessTitleText = showMoreOrLessTitleText
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700668/5457853 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76835756/preventing-unnecessary-recompositions-on-list-updates-in-jetpack-compose/76837109#76837109 for LazyColumn recompositon and stability. Also you need to check stability, since it's kotlin dsl for gradle file i didn't check stability of functions and types

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have one question. What is the purpose of remembering the lambda function across recompositions to what I was doing before. As I was handling the events in my ViewModel. Just trying to get my head around remembering a lambda function. I can understand remembering states as states can change, but would the lambda function change? I have never done that with a lambda.  Is this something we should always do? An example would be great.

Comment: @ant2009 you can see the example in stackoverflow.com/a/74700668/5457853 in this answer's `Stability Edit` section. I don't know how to set stability task in gradle dsl but if you do it and run it you will see that ViewModel is unstable and function calls to it in lambda triggers recomposition. Initially i was thinking function references should not trigger recompostion but even they do. So in such a case you should check for stability of lambda either.

Comment: When you read something unstable inside lambda it triggers recomposition because of that if you remember it, with keys if you want to reset it under some condition, best solution is to use remember when stability is an issue. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter4_state/Tutorial4_2_7LambdaRecomposition.kt

Answer (score 0):

Make a `rememberLazyListState` like this:

```
val lazyColumnListState = rememberLazyListState()
```

And pass it to your `LazyColumn` like so:

```
LazyColumn(
    state = lazyColumnListState,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 8.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(6.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    items(
        key = { articleModel ->
            articleModel.id
        },
        items = newsPagingData.itemSnapshotList.items
    ) { articleModel ->
        NewsItem(
            articleModel = articleModel,
            onNewsLinkClicked = onNewsLinkedClicked,
            newsItemEvent = newsItemEvent,
            newsItemState = newsItemState,
            titleTextLayoutResult = ::getTextLayoutResult
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: And how is that going to help?