Compose: Using SnapshotStateMap to avoid recomposition of every item in a map
I have an app that reads properties from a file. The file can be changed outside of my application, it can be deleted or fully replaced. My goal is to read the .properties file  and show a preferences like screen where they can modify each property.
This is my first app with compose and I am not sure how to achieve this.
From what I have read so far in order for the state to be reflected in your UI you need to change the entire instance of array/properties. From my understanding that is going to trigger a recomposition of all elements. That be be avoided with SnapshotStateMap (?).
So my code currently looks like this:
View model
@HiltViewModel(assistedFactory = SettingsViewModel.Factory::class)
class SettingsViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(@Assisted properties: Properties) : ViewModel() {

    private val prefs = SnapshotStateMap<String, Any>()

    init {
        properties.forEach {
            prefs[it.key.toString()] = it.value
        }
    }

    fun getPref(key: String, default: String): String {
        return prefs[key]?.toString() ?: default
    }

    fun updatePref(key: String, value: Any) {
        prefs[key] = value
    }
    ...
}

// Pref class
data class Pref<T>(val key: String, @StringRes val title: Int, val default: T)

UI
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val vm: SettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel<SettingsViewModel, SettingsViewModel.Factory>(
        creationCallback = { factory ->
            factory.create(FileUtils.getProperties(context))
        }
    )

    SettingsColumn {

           SettingsSwitchComp(
                pref = Prefs.pref1,
                getValue = { key, default -> vm.getPref(key, default) },
                onClick = { vm.updatePref(Prefs.pref1.key, !it) }
            )
           SettingsSwitchComp(
                pref = Prefs.pref2,
                getValue = { key, default -> vm.getPref(key, default) },
                onClick = { vm.updatePref(Prefs.pref2.key, !it) }
            )
    }
}

@Composable
fun SettingsSwitchComp(
    pref: Pref<Boolean>,
    getValue: (String, Boolean) -> Boolean,
    onClick: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val value = getValue(pref.key, pref.default)
    Surface(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
        onClick = { onClick(value) },
    ) {
        Column {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = pref.title),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Switch(
                    checked = getValue(pref.key, pref.default),
                    onCheckedChange = { onClick(value) }
                )
            }
            HorizontalDivider()
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun SettingsColumn(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        content()
    }
}

But if I toggle one switch, both of them get recomposed. So I am obviously missing something about the usage of SnapshotStateMap...
Any advice appreciated.

Have you checked if your if Pref is stable? Both SnapshotStateMap and SnapshotStateList works same way. You can refer these answers for list in lazy column to avoid unnecessary recompositions which also works for map counterpart. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76835756/preventing-unnecessary-recompositions-on-list-updates-in-jetpack-compose/76837109#76837109 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700668/5457853

@Thracian could you elaborate on what would make Pref stable? Other than annotating it with @Stable I havent found any other requirements - and it did not help my cause.

The problem was in the way a was sending the value to my composables:
getValue = { key, default -> vm.getPref(key, default) }

sending it as a function triggered unnecessary recompositions. Instead when using:
value = vm.getPref(key, default)

only the composable that has been updated has triggered a recomposition.
