# Adding Single Item in a SnapshotStateList causes all visible items to recompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have a scenario where I add item(s) to a `SnapshotStateList<T>` inside the `ViewModel`. This list of items gets displayed using a `LazyColumn` in the UI.

This is my ViewModel class

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val data = mutableStateListOf<String>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch { loadData() }
    }

    private suspend fun loadData() {
        // I am adding items after a delay to simulate
        // items getting added from a flow/other sources
        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(1))

        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(2))

        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(3))

        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(4))

        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(5))
    }

    private fun sampleText(id: Int): String = "Sample Text $id"
}
```

The UI consists of a single `LazyColumn` Composable.

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()) {
    TextList(textItems = viewModel.data)
}

@Composable
fun TextList(textItems: List<String>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(textItems, key = { it.hashCode() }) {
            println("TextList: Composing Text = $it")
            Text(text = it)
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see the `println()` line for each item as they get added to the list. However, this is what I see in the logs:

```
2023-08-12 21:55:30.352 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 1
2023-08-12 21:55:30.895 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 1
2023-08-12 21:55:30.905 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 2
2023-08-12 21:55:32.899 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 1
2023-08-12 21:55:32.902 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 2
2023-08-12 21:55:32.912 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 3
2023-08-12 21:55:34.918 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 1
2023-08-12 21:55:34.921 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 2
2023-08-12 21:55:34.923 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 3
2023-08-12 21:55:34.931 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 4
2023-08-12 21:55:36.919 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 1
2023-08-12 21:55:36.922 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 2
2023-08-12 21:55:36.925 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 3
2023-08-12 21:55:36.931 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 4
2023-08-12 21:55:36.943 29930-29930 System.out  I  TextList: Composing Text = Sample Text 5
```

I am confused as to why all the previously added items get's re-composed every time a new item is added to the list?

This seems related to [Jetpack Compose lazy column all items recomposes when a single item update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699081/jetpack-compose-lazy-column-all-items-recomposes-when-a-single-item-update), but the solution didn't help here.

Edit #1:
As suggested by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), I did flatten out the UI and moving the `TextList` but the results don't change

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(viewModel.data, key = { it.hashCode() }) {
            println("TextList: Composing Text = $it")
            Text(text = it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Flatten your setup, by putting the `LazyColumn()` directly in `HomeScreen()` and getting rid of `TextList()`. That puts the reference to your `SnapshotStateList` (`viewModel.data`) in the  `items()` call, instead of it being outside the `LazyColumn()` as you have it now. Do your results change?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can confirm that the results don't change.

Comment: I don’t think this is causing your problem, but the lambda you’re passing for `key` is wrong. First, `it` in this case is the index of the item in the list, not the item itself, so it doesn’t make sense to use `it.hashCode` , but also, you must not use hashcodes at all because they aren’t guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I would disagree, as per the documentation https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys and based on the lamda definition in the source code: `key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null`.

Comment: You’re right about that—I was looking at [this other overload](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#items(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2)) of `items`. But you still shouldn’t use hashcode because a hashcode is not guaranteed unique. You could possibly use the String itself if the Strings never repeat in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will skip Text compositions, regardless of using the key or not. To see the effect of the key in LazyColumn, modify the code slightly.

```kotlin
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val data = mutableStateListOf<String>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch { loadData() }
    }

    private suspend fun loadData() {
        // I am adding items after a delay to simulate
        // items getting added from a flow/other sources
        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(1))

        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(2))

        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(3))

        delay(2000L)
        data.add(sampleText(4))

        delay(2000L)
        data.add(0 ,sampleText(5)) // add Sample Text 5 at the index 0
    }

    private fun sampleText(id: Int): String = "Sample Text $id"
}
```

The code will not recompositions of Text if you don't use any key on items. When Sample Text 5 is added, recompositions will happen.

```
Sample Text 1 // this will be recomposed to Sample Text 5
Sample Text 2 // this will be recomposed to Sample Text 1
Sample Text 3 // this will be recomposed to Sample Text 2
Sample Text 4 // this will be recomposed to Sample Text 3
// a new Text will be created as Sample Text 4
```

But, when you specifiy the key of items, recompositions will be skipped. You can check it on the layout inspector.

[image: With id, recompositions skipped]

The numbers on the right side are skip counts.

Answer (score 0):

The desired behaviour of a `SnapshotStateList` is to recompose when even one of the item gets changed or updated.

Try using `mutableListof()` if you want to recompose only when the entire list has been changed.