# How to iterate through a list with unique clickable items in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, iteration

Hello and thanks in advance for considering my question.  I would like to iterate through a list and be able to have the user click on an item to expand the item's card to show more content.  The following code does show a list with separate cards for each item.  However, when you click on a card all cards expand.  I would like to be able to only expand the card that is selected.  Here's my code:

```
@Composable
fun myList() {


    var myList = listOf("Canada", "China", "USA", "Pakistan")
    var expanded: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LazyColumn(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
    )
    {

        items(myList) { countries ->

            ElevatedCard(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        expanded = !expanded
                    },
                shape = CardDefaults.elevatedShape,
                colors = CardDefaults.elevatedCardColors(),
                elevation = CardDefaults.elevatedCardElevation()
            ) {

                Text(text = "$countries")

                if (expanded) {
                    Text(text = "Content")
                }

            }


        }

    }

}
```

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the code and will help you.
Can you try the code below:

```
    @Composable
   fun myList() {
       
       val myList = listOf("Canada", "China", "USA", "Pakistan")
       var expandedItems by remember { mutableStateOf(setOf<String>()) }
       
       LazyColumn(
           Modifier
               .fillMaxWidth()
               .padding(10.dp)
       )
       {

           items(myList.size) { index ->

               ElevatedCard(
                   modifier = Modifier
                       .fillMaxWidth()
                       .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                       .clickable {
                           expandedItems = if (expandedItems.contains(myList[index])) {
                               expandedItems - myList[index]
                           } else {
                               expandedItems + myList[index]
                           }
                       },
                   shape = CardDefaults.elevatedShape,
                   colors = CardDefaults.elevatedCardColors(),
                   elevation = CardDefaults.elevatedCardElevation()
               ) {

                   Text(text = "$myList[index]")

                   if (expandedItems.contains(myList[index])) {
                       Text(text = "Content")
                   }

               }
           }

           }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a data class that contains selected variable and other data inside a SnapshotStateList. When user touches any expandable item set current item with copy changing only selected property to opposite of current value.

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699081/jetpack-compose-lazy-column-all-items-recomposes-when-a-single-item-update/74700668#74700668) for more details, optimizing for minimum recomposition and stability of Composables as well.