# ViewModel does not update list of Object after changes. How to fix this?

Tags: viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a ViewModel class:

```
class ItemsModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _tasks = MutableStateFlow<List<TaskItem>>(listOf())

    val tasks = _tasks.asStateFlow()

    fun onTaskDone(index: Int) {
        _tasks.value = _tasks.value.toMutableList().apply {
            get(index).task.done = !get(index).task.done
        }
    }

    fun onTaskRemove(index: Int) {
        val listSize = _tasks.value.size
        _tasks.value = _tasks.value.toMutableList().apply {
            if (index < listSize)
                removeAt(index)
        }
    }


    fun addTask(task: String) {
        _tasks.value = _tasks.value.toMutableList().apply {
            add(TaskItem(this.size + 1, Task(task)))
        }
    }
}
```

The data class of `TaskItem`:

```
@Parcelize
data class TaskItem(var index: Int, var task: Task) : Parcelable
```

The data class of `Task`:

```
@Parcelize
data class Task(var task: String = "", var done: Boolean = false) : Parcelable
```

In the target composable screen I call that like this:

```
...
val itemsModel: ItemsModel = viewModel()
val tasks by itemsModel.tasks.collectAsState()
...
```

Whenever I call this `itemsModel.onTaskDone(index)` the `LazyColumn` doesn't get updated until another changes are made to the list, e.g. adding new task item into the list.

So far I understand, that change doesn't take place on `LazyColumn` since I change a value within the Object `Task` that is a variable within `TaskItem`. If I had a `String` instead of `Task` the changes could appear immediately, don't they?

Anyway, I need to get changes shown in `LazyColumn`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foun a solution if someone should be still loocking for.

I jst defined a new `SnapshotStateList` variable within screen:

```
var tasks = remember { mutableStateListOf<Task>() }
```

It allows changing data within the list and recompose `LazyColumn` like this:

```
val item = tasks[index]
tasks[index] = item.copy(done = !tasks[index].done)
```

For more info please also check this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699081/jetpack-compose-lazy-column-all-items-recomposes-when-a-single-item-update).

Please make sure that you also set a key for `LazyColumn`:

```
itemsIndexed(tasks, key = { _, task -> task.hashCode() }) { index, task -> /* Your code */ }
```